# Scroll UITableView so that the header isn't visible

Tags: iphone, search, uitableview, scroll, uisearchbar

I've got a UITableView with a UISearchBar as the tableViews.tableHeaderView. Just like the new Mail.app, Notes.app, etc. in 3.0. I want to hide the SearchBar until the user drags it in his sight.

My attempt only works when there're a couple of items in the tableView, so that the tableView actually wants to scroll. I call this in loadView:

```
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];
[self._tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:indexPath atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:NO];
```

Nevertheless it seems that Apple handles such a serachbar differently. After draging out the searchbar it doesn't seem to be bounded to the tablecells anymore (in Notes.app, not in Mail.app).

But perhaps Apple has a distinct method for that new 3.0 behaviour, and I just can't find it?

Comment: Checkout couple of new properties for `UIViewController`. [https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TransitionGuide/AppearanceCustomization.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013174-CH15-SW1](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TransitionGuide/AppearanceCustomization.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013174-CH15-SW1)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Maybe you can try it this way...

```
[self.tableView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0,40)];
```

Comment: Need to do it every time after table view is reloaded. [self.tableView reloadData];

Comment: Doesn't work when the number of rows are less than the total number of rows that fit on the screen. Any known workarounds for this scenario?

Comment: Anyone has an answer for @Zorayr comment ?

Answer (score 25):

Worked for me too. I used the following:

```
[self.tableView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, self.searchDisplayController.searchBar.frame.size.height) animated:NO];
```

to query the height of the search bar.

Comment: Lovelly and simple, though I added the animated:YES parameter so improve the look of the thing.

Comment: Perfect! Simply added it in viewWillAppear and I got the result I was looking for.

Answer (score 10):

This one gets you the exact same behavior as iPod.app:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
 [super viewWillAppear:animated];

 CGFloat searchBarHeight = CGRectGetHeight([[[self searchDisplayController] searchBar] frame]);
 if ([[self tableView] contentOffset].y < searchBarHeight)
  [[self tableView] setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, searchBarHeight)];
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This works for me.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.tableView.bounces = YES;
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    [self.tableView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, 44)];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to scroll first to top then `setContentOffset` to `0`, Then searchBar will be visible :

```
self.tableView.scrollToRowAtIndexPath(NSIndexPath(forRow: 0, inSection: 0), atScrollPosition: UITableViewScrollPosition.Top, animated: false)
self.tableView.setContentOffset(CGPointMake(0, 0), animated: false)
```

Answer (score -2):

I kind of like doing it this way:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    // Hide the table view header by default.
    NSIndexPath *index = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];
    [self.tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:index atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:NO];
}
```

This way you don't really need to worry about how tall your header is. It just works!

Comment: The solution crashes the app if the table view hasn't loaded the rows or has zero rows.

Comment: Oh gotcha. Thanks for the comment Zorayr