# Problems with UISearchBar not working like in stock apps (scrolling under UINavigationBar)

Tags: ios, objective-c, hide, uinavigationbar, uisearchbar

I've got a problem in that I cannot get my UISearchBar to scroll underneath my UINavigationBar.

```
-(void)awakeFromNib
{
    [super awakeFromNib];

    self.tableView.tableHeaderView = self.taskSearchBar;
}

-(UIView*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return self.taskSearchBar;
}

-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 44;
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {

    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    self.tableView.frame = self.view.bounds;

    // Load our table with current data
    [self.tableView reloadData];

    // Tuck UISearchBar under navigation bar
    self.tableView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0, self.taskSearchBar.frame.size.height);
}
```

I've spent a LOT of time searching through SO to try to find relevant discussions.

This one, for example, makes it sound OH SO SIMPLE: [Scroll UITableView so that the header isn't visible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1080274/scroll-uitableview-so-that-the-header-isnt-visible)

I was previously able to get this to work when creating everything from Story Board, but I can no longer do that due to the nature of my app - I had to break things out to have a parent UIView to the UITableView which I was unable to do while using a UITableViewController.

Any help on this would be MUCH appreciated!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are assigning the search bar as the tableHeaderView which will be what you need I think. BUT you are returning it as a section header for every section which is not logical(I guess you need this search bar show only in one place). Section headers are always visible and that is what's causing your problem I think.

Comment: I only have one section in this UITableView.

Based on your response, section headers are always visible, so this is why it won't slide under the UINavigationBar.  Can you please give me a DIFFERENT way to get the UISearchBar into my view that will work properly?

Comment: It doesn't matter. The search bar will always stay over the cells because of the behavior of the section headers I explained. And using the same search bar in two different places could be confusing for the OS

Comment: You can add both the search bar and the table view as subviews of a scroll view but ...hmm that would be unnecessarily complicated. Just using the tableViewHeader should work. Is there some other use case that is not covered by the header approach?

Comment: Let me try phrasing this differently...

1. I do indeed have the UISearchBar being returned in viewForHeaderInSection

2. If I don't do that (1), then there is no visible UISearchBar in my app whatsoever

3. Is there some OTHER way I can HAVE a UISearchBar that will allow me to actually have it scroll up underneath my UINavigationBar?

Comment: Move self.tableView.tableHeaderView = self.taskSearchBar; into viewDidLoad because I suspect awakeFromNib is not called and delete the section header related methods. That's the cleanest way possible. Any other way is a bad approach and overcomplicated.

Comment: Well that helped.  Now the UISearchBar WILL scroll under the UINavigationBar.

Unfortunately though, the topmost cell (the one directly below the UISearchBar) now has white space equivalent in vertical height to the UISearchBar...

http://postimg.org/image/f28aeh1gx/

Comment: // Tuck UISearchBar under navigation bar
    self.tableView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0, self.taskSearchBar.frame.size.height); this row scrolls down the exact amount of space we see on the picture.